# Is this sentence with "assured were safe turned out to be" grammatically wrong?

Tags: grammar

> "Investments they had been assured **were** safe **turned** out to be
>   highly risky."

I am confused with two conjugated verbs *were* and *turned*.

I think *were* should be changed into *of being*. Is there a relative clause?

Comment: Oh I've typed the title wrong. It is "Is this sentence grammatically wrong?"

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. On this site, it's better to [edit] than to comment about explain what went wrong. Try to use a more descriptive title so that people scanning the [list of titles](https://english.stackexchange.com/) have some idea of what your question is about.

Comment: Once you've edited your title, you can delete your initial comment. To delete a comment, move your mouse over the comment. An 'x' will pop up at the end of the comment. Click "OK" to confirm the deletion.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. It's grammatical and makes sense. Please see also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you. But why can "certain investments" be omitted?

Answer (score 2):

In your sentence, *something* turned out to be highly risky.  What was it that turned out to be risky?  Well, it was the investments.  But wait, which investments were risky?  Why, it was the *investments **that they had been assured were safe***.

The clause about the investments being safe simply describes which investments are being discussed.  You could drop that clause and still get the main idea:

> Investments turned out to be highly risky.

But perhaps it wasn't all investments, so the writer specified that it was the ones they thought were safe.

Alternatively, you might have also said:

> Investments *that they thought were risky* turned out to be rather safe.

Answer (score 0):

"Is there a relative clause?" Yes, there is. It is "they had been assured were safe". The sentence means about the same thing as the two sentences "They had been assured (that) certain investments were safe. Those investments turned out to be highly risky."

Relative clauses in English have "gaps" that are understood to refer to the same thing as the antecedent of the noun phrase, even though the noun is not repeated in the relative clause. In fact, it would be ungrammatical to repeat the noun in the relative clause.

If we mark the gap with the symbol "t<sub>1</sub>" (which doesn't correspond to any spoken element of the sentence), we can write the structure of the sentence as follows:

> [Investments<sub>1</sub> [they had been assured t<sub>1</sub> were safe]] turned out to be highly risky.

There would also be a gap in any other relative clause like this:

> [Investments<sub>1</sub> [they had recommended t<sub>1</sub>]] turned out to be highly risky.

(This complex sentence means "They had recommended certain investments. Those investments turned out to be highly risky.")